# I wish to write a code to answer an infinite series,which has alternationg add and subtract operations.I cannot see the error,in my code

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, series

I have written below for loop, and every time i execute below code i get the FinalResult answer AS 1.

What is wrong with my code?

1-1/2+1/3-1/4+1/5-1/6.......till n terms

```
package Practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeriesHW {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Till what number you want to calculate this series?");
        int n=input.nextInt();


        int resultone = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i=i+2) {

             resultone+=1/i;

        }
        int resulttwo = 0;
        for(int j=2;j<=n;j=j+2) {

        resulttwo+=1/j;

       }
      int finalresult=resultone-resulttwo;
      System.out.println("Answer is : " + finalresult);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think the Code is wrong what is the expected result? I think your problem is the type of resultone and resulttwo. Or should be a float or double? And please do not use upper case characters only in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...I am using my this site for the first time...what do you mean by where not to use uppercase ?

Comment: Upper case words means shouting.

Comment: Will keep that in mind...thanks

Comment: I think you are using the wrong data types.   Here is a clue:  `1/i` will be zero ... because you are dividing an integer by an integer, and that produces an integer in Java.

Comment: Hey...i changed to ddouble and even float,but still it is not working..i have edited the post by adding the question itself...please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Use `BigDecimal` instead of `int` because the Java's auto boxing will cause lot of trouble when you bring `int` in a decimal world either as variable or as a literal

Note: Currently rounded of decimal to celing and kept the scale as 2 at below line 
`resultone = resultone.add(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(i),2, RoundingMode.CEILING));`

Feel free to update it as per your need.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeriesHW {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Till what number you want to calculate this series?");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        BigDecimal resultone = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 2) {
            resultone = resultone.add(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(i),2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
        }
        BigDecimal resulttwo = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (int j = 2; j <= n; j = j + 2) {

            resulttwo = resulttwo.add(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(j),2, RoundingMode.CEILING));

        }
        BigDecimal finalresult = resultone.subtract(resulttwo) ;
        System.out.println("Answer is : " + finalresult);
    }

}
```

Output :

```
Till what number you want to calculate this series?
10
Answer is : 0.66
```